# Error al abrir un fichero DELPHI

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-2010

Estoy tratando de abrir un fichero de un archivo que cree previamente de tipo .dat

Es un registro que contiene otros registros

```
type mapa = record // record que guarda todo el proyecto
mcM,mcT,mcC,mcE,mcD,mcV,mcB,mCMed : Integer; // Contadores de los componentes

// Arreglos dinámicos para guardar la información
mAmangeras : array[0..10000] of manguera;
mAtubos : array[0..10000] of tubo;
mAcasas : array[0..10000] of home;
mAEdificos : array[0..10000] of buiding;
mAdist : array[0..10000] of distribuidor;
mAValv : array[0..10000] of vavlula;
mAbomb : array[0..10000] of bombas;
mAmed : array[0..10000] of med;
// Fin arreglos

end;
```

Lo que hago es guardar un registro de tipo mapa en un archivo .dat con el siguiente código
donde plano memoria es el registro de tipo mapa a guardar y el procedimietno crearArchivoDeRegistro guarda los datos.

```
if FileExists(fileName) then
    begin
      if MessageDlg('El archivo ya existe, desea remplazarlo?',mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo],
              0, mbYes) = mrYes then
        begin
          Rewrite (f);
          crearArchivoDeRegistro();
          Write(f, PlanoMeoria);
          CloseFile(f);
          Edit1.Text := ' ';
          Close();
        end;
    end
    else
    begin
      Rewrite (f);
      crearArchivoDeRegistro();
      Write(f, PlanoMeoria);
      CloseFile(f);
      Edit1.Text := ' ';
      Close();
    end;


end;
```

Se guarda sin mandar ningún error, sin embargo cuando trato de abrir el archivo con este codigo me manda I/O error 6

```
// Display the open file dialog
  If (OpenDialog.Execute) then
    begin
      AssignFile(f, openDialog.Name);
      reset(F);
       while not Eof do // AQUI OCURRE EL ERROR
       read(F, archivoParaAbrir); // AQUI OCURRE EL ERROR
      CloseFile(F);
      //abrirArchivosContenedoresDePlanos(archivoParaAbrir);
    end;

  // Free up the dialog
  openDialog.Free;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que no usas la propiedad correcta, prueba con

```
openDialog.FileName
```

Comment: Mira Cómo responder para que tu respuesta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta llamar **EOF** con el archivo **f** que intentas probar si llegaste a fin de línea :

```
// Display the open file dialog
  If (OpenDialog.Execute) then
    begin
      AssignFile(f, openDialog.Name);
      reset(F);
       while not Eof(f) do // <==== AQUI llamar EOF con el archivo como parámetro
       read(F, archivoParaAbrir); // si esta vacío o llego al final ya no entra aquí
      CloseFile(F);
      //abrirArchivosContenedoresDePlanos(archivoParaAbrir);
    end;

  // Free up the dialog
  openDialog.Free;
```